# Snowflake JavaScript UDTF not compiling - Split word without delimiters

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In SQL server the SPLIT function without indicating the delimiter will split the string by each letter.
But in Snowflake the SPLIT function without a delimiter will return the exact same string.

So, the solution was to create a JavaScript function to do the split, returning a table with the index of the letter and the letter.
This is the JavaScript UDTF function in Snowflake:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION split_word(WORD VARCHAR)
        RETURNS TABLE (ID smallint, LETTER CHAR(1))
        LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
        AS $$
          {
            initialize: function (argumentInfo, context) {/*...*/},
            processRow: function (row, rowWriter, context) {
               var ccount = 0;
               var warray = row.WORD.split('');
               var wlen = row.WORD.length;
               while (ccount < wlen) {
                 rowWriter.writeRow( {ID: ccount + 1},{LETTER: warray[ccount]} );
                 ccount = ccount + 1;
               }
            },
            finalize: function (rowWriter, context) {/*...*/}
          }
          $$;
```

But when I execute it `select * from table(split_word('Jose'));` it fails compiling or query repairing:

```
    000603 (XX000): SQL execution internal error:
    Processing aborted due to error 300010:3011697808; incident 3311582.
```

It's quite simple and it does work in JavaScript:

```
    word='Jose';
    var ccount = 0;
    var warray = word.split('');
    var wlen = word.length
    while (ccount < wlen) {
        console.log( {ID: ccount + 1,LETTER: warray[ccount]} );
      ccount = ccount + 1;
    }
```

returns:

```
>node .\split.js
{ ID: 1, LETTER: 'J' }
{ ID: 2, LETTER: 'o' }
{ ID: 3, LETTER: 's' }
{ ID: 4, LETTER: 'e' }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snowflake SQL is expressive enough to hadle it using built-in SPLIT_TO_TABLE
(with small assistance on the input data):

Sample data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab(col TEXT)
AS
SELECT 'Jose' UNION ALL
SELECT 'The brown fox';
```

Clue - inserting delimiter between each character:

```
SELECT *, REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '(.)', '\\1~')
FROM tab;
```

Output:

[image]

Split using SPLIT_TO_TABLE based on introduced deliter:

```
SELECT tab.col, sp.index, sp.value
FROM tab,  
 TABLE(SPLIT_TO_TABLE(TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '(.)', '\\1~'), '~'), '~')) AS sp
ORDER BY tab.col, sp.index;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Nice trick deceiving the SPLIT_TO_TABLE function, regex to the rescue. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The [first answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73916665/2701228) from Lukasz Szozda brought a way to do the split by word without the need of a JavaScript function.

But also, [in Snowflake Community I got another answer](https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D73r000006yENSCA2/detail) on why the function was not working.

Turns out the return table declaration shall not include INT when the language of the UDTF is JavaScipt, to refer to numbers what shall be used is double or float. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/javascript/udf-javascript-introduction.html#integers-and-doubles

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION split_word(WORD VARCHAR)
RETURNS TABLE (ID double, LETTER CHAR(1))
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS $$
  {
    initialize: function (argumentInfo, context) {/*...*/},
    processRow: function (row, rowWriter, context) {
       var ccount = 0;
       var warray = row.WORD.split('');
       var wlen = row.WORD.length;
       while (ccount < wlen) {
         rowWriter.writeRow( {ID: ccount + 1,LETTER: warray[ccount]} );
         ccount = ccount + 1;
       }
    },
    finalize: function (rowWriter, context) {/*...*/}
  }
  $$;
```

[image: Blockquote]